# How to Print the Contents of a Vector of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Please I have a vector of a person called nodes. I read from a file into the nodes vector. When I try printing out the contents of the vector, my code compiles but does not print anything. Below is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am still new to C++

```
class person {

public:
    //int person_id;
    string name;
    int age;
    float spread_probability;


    person(){

     }

    person (string pname, int page, double spread){
        //person_id = p_id;
        name = pname;
        age = page;
        spread_probability = spread;
    }
};
vector <string*> edges;
vector <person> nodes;

void insert_node(person& p, string name, int age, float spread_probability) 
{
    p.name = name;
    p.age = age;
    p.spread_probability = spread_probability;
    nodes.push_back(p);
}


void print_node(person& p){
    cout << p.name << " " << p.age << " " << p.spread_probability << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
        cout<< nodes[i].name <<":"; 
    }
}

// This is the main function 
int main() {
    ifstream inf("smallpopulation.dat");

    // If we couldn't open the output file stream for reading
    if (!inf) {
        // Print an error and exit
        cerr << "Uh oh, population.dat could not be opened for reading!" << 
        endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // While there's still stuff left to read
    while (inf) {
        string n;
        int a;
        double s;

        inf >> n >> a >> s;
        insert_node(nodes[0], n, a, s);
    }

    print_node(nodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may overload operator<< as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

class Node {
public:
  Node():x(0), s("string"){}
  Node(int _x, std::string _s):x(_x),s(_s){}
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, Node n);
private:
  int x;
  std::string s;
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, Node n)
{
  o<<"("<<n.x<<","<<n.s<<") ";
  return o;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Node n1 = Node();
  Node n2 = Node(12,"apple");
  Node n3 = Node(100, "rat");
  std::cout<<n1<<" "<<n2<<std::endl;
  //this print gives the following output:
  //(0,string)  (12,apple)
  //here the vector of Node objects is created:
  std::vector<Node> vec;
  vec.push_back(n1);
  vec.push_back(n2);
  vec.push_back(n3);
  //size of the vector of Node objects:
  std::cout<<"size="<<vec.size()<<std::endl;
  //here the vector of Node objects is printed:
  for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) std::cout<<vec.at(i)<<"  ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My code just worked. I feel so happy

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
void print_node(person& p){
for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
  cout<< i <<":"; 
}
```

does nothing but print `i`, and `i` is just an `int`.

Before we can print a vector of `person`, we must be able to print *one* `person`. You haven't shown us the definition of `person`, but the class seems to contain (at least) three member variables. So we could have a function like this:

```
void print_node(person& p){
  cout << p.name << " " << p.age << " " << p.spread_probability << endl;
}
```

Then to print a vector of them:

```
for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
  print_node(nodes[i]);
}
```

or:

```
for(vector<person>::iterator itr=nodes.begin(); itr!=nodes.end(); ++itr){
  print_node(*itr);
}
```

Once you have that much working, many refinements are possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try that

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to make an overload for the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const person& p)` operator and then use range-based loop rather than using these hard to read iterators explicitly?

Comment: I am really new to C++ so I do not really get what you mean. But I have tried editing the code and the same problem persists. You can find the edited code above

Comment: I really appreciate. Thank you so much. It worked finally

Comment: @ProXicT: When I write an Answer for a beginner, I try to keep things simple. And when I do, I sometimes end with "once you have this much working, many refinements are possible". And when I do, sure as night follows day, someone posts a comment: *"it would be better with this refinement..."*

Comment: I see, you've got a point there :) Well, I've just written up an answer myself and maybe someone else will find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_node(person& p){
for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
    cout<< i <<":"; 
}
}
```

The problem is there. U're actually don't tell code to print anything. U could try something like:

```
cout << i << nodes[i].age;
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Let me try it. But how can I print out everything at once?

Comment: I have tried that too. It still was not printing anything out.

Comment: One way is to list the properties with the `<<` operator, like `... << nodes[i].age << nodes[i].name << ...` (u may want to put some spaces too)

Comment: A useful way to debug ur code is to put a breakpoint on the line with `cout`. This way u can see what is inside the vector and verify if the problem comes from previous executed code

Comment: Sure. I'll try that also

Comment: I do not know why but it seems not to print either.

Comment: By debugging u're not looking at the stuff the code prints (u're supposed to know already). When the break point is hit u could hover over a variable in order to see its content, depending of the IDE u use. In our case u shall hover the vector and see if `person` objs are built right

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not printing any information from the `person` class.
But you have more problems in your code apart from printing. First of all, your `insert` function is inefficient and hard to read. Actually, you don't even need an `insert` function at all in your case. You can use the `std::vector::emplace_back()` function, for example:

```
nodes.emplace_back("name", 38, 1.4f);
```

This will call the constructor for `person` and create the object in your `vector` of `person`s.

To print the `vector<person>`, you can make a function which will print one `person` object instance:

```
void printPerson(const person& p) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << p.name << 
        "\nAge: " << p.age <<
        "\nSpread probability: " << p.spread_probability;
}
```

Which was already suggested and would definitely work, but there is a better option and that is to overload the `operator<<` for `std::ostream`, which is what `std::cout` derives from:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const person& p)
{
    out << "Name: " << p.name << 
        "\nAge: " << p.age <<
        "\nSpread probability: " << p.spread_probability;
    return out;
}
```

Then you just need to call this function for every object you want to print.

---

To wrap it up, this would be the whole main function:

```
int main() 
{
    ifstream inf("smallpopulation.dat");
    vector<person> nodes;

    // If we couldn't open the output file stream for reading
    if (!inf) {
        // Print an error and exit
        cerr << "Uh oh, population.dat could not be opened for reading!" << 
        endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // While there's still stuff left to read
    while (inf) {
        string n;
        int a;
        double s;

        inf >> n >> a >> s;
        nodes.emplace_back(n, a, s);
    }

    // Goes through all instances of `nodes`
    for (const person& p : nodes) {
        cout << p << '\n'; // calls the `std::ostream& operator<<` defined above...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked, if you need to explain anything, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Sure. Thanks once again